# Sprites sequence control through DeltaTime

Tags: c++, algorithm, sprite, sdl-2, timedelta

Previously in my main loop of the game, the time was managed at 60 FPS and the respective Delay for the time delay.

The Sprite sequence was animated as follows:

```
<pre>
if(++ciclos > 10){
   siguienteSprite++;
   ciclos = 0;
}
</pre>
```

Given that I am using Smooth Motion with DeltaTime, therefore I have eliminated Delay from the Main Cycle; Making this the sprites cycles of the animation are faster, and not only this, but also the time between each sequence varies.

Someone could give me a hand, only with the logic of this problem, beforehand thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delay` in main loop is not really a good way for this (as it is not accounting for the time other stuff in your main loop takes). When you removed delay then the speed is bigger and varying more  because the other stuff in your main loop timing is more significant and usually non constant for many reasons like:

- **OS** granularity
- synchronization with gfx card/driver
- non constant processing times

There are more ways how to handle this:

1. **measure time**

   ```
   <pre>
   t1=get_actual_time();
   while (t1-t0>=animation_T)
    {
    siguienteSprite++;
    t0+=animation_T;
    }
   // t0=t1; // this is optional and change the timing properties a bit
   </pre>
   ```

   where `t0` is some global variable holding "last" measured time os sprite change. `t1` is actual time and `animation_T` is time constant between animation changes. To measure time you need to use **OS** api like `PerformanceCounter` on windows or `RDTSC` in asm or any other you got at hand but with small enough resolution.
2. **OS timer**

   simply increment the `siguienteSprite` in some timer with `animation_T` interval. This is simple but OS timers are not precise and usually of around 1ms or more + OS granularity (similar to `Sleep` accuracy).
3. **Thread timer**

   you can create single thread for timing purposes for example something like this:

   ```
   for (;!threads_stop;)
    {
    Delay(animation_T); // or Sleep()
    siguienteSprite++;
    }
   ```

   Do not forget that `siguienteSprite` must be `volatile` and buffered during rendering to avoid flickering and or access violation errors. This approach is a bit more precise (unless you got single core **CPU**).

   You cam also increment some time variable instead and use that as actual time in your app with any resolution you want. But beware if `delay` is not returning  **CPU** control to **OS** then this approach will utilize your **CPU** to `100%/CPU_cores`. There is remedy for this and that is replacing your `delay` with this:

   ```
   Sleep(0.9*animation_T);
   for (;;)
    {
    t1=get_actual_time();
    if (t1-t0>=animation_T)
     {
     siguienteSprite++;
     t0=t1;
     break;
     }
   ```

If you are using measured time then you should handle overflows `(t1<t0)` because any counter will overflow after time. For example using 32bit part of **RDTSC**  on `3.2 GHz` **CPU core** will overflow every `2^32/3.2e9 = 1.342 sec` so it is real possibility. If my memory serves well then Performance counters in Windows usually runs around `3.5 MHz` on older **OS** systems and around `60-120 MHz` on newer (at least last time I check) and are 64 bit so the overflows are not that big of a problem (unless you run 24/7). Also in case of **RDTSC** use you should set process/thread affinity to single **CPU** core to avoid timing problems on multi core **CPU**s.

I did my share of benchmarking and advanced high resolution timing at low level over the years so here few related **QA**s of mine:

[wrong clock cycle measurements with rdtsc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572772/2521214) - OS Granularity

[Measuring Cache Latencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21548494/2521214) - measuring CPU frequency

[Cache size estimation on your system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21509808/2521214) - `PerformanceCounter` example

[Questions on Measuring Time Using the CPU Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21573076/2521214) - PIT as alternative timing source