# Fixed time step stutter even with interpolation?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

First let me describe what I mean by stutter. When the player moves it looks as if it moves forward a little then back to where it should be and keeps doing it. I am making a small game for learning purposes in lwjgl3 and I am using JOML as my math library. I implemented a fixed time step loop (FPS = 60 and UPS = 30) and I use interpolation to try and smooth my player movement. It works nicely sometimes (not as smooth as I want it though) but other times its just as stuttery as without it. Any ideas on how to fix this? Am I doing the interpolation correctly?

Game Loop:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    window.init("Game", 1280, 720);
    GL.createCapabilities();

    gameApp.init();

    timer.init();

    float delta;
    float accumulator = 0f;
    float interval = 1f / Settings.TARGET_UPS;
    float alpha;

    while (running) {
        delta = timer.getDelta();
        accumulator += delta;

        gameApp.input();

        while (accumulator >= interval) {
            gameApp.update();
            timer.updateUPS();
            accumulator -= interval;
        }

        alpha = accumulator / interval;

        gameApp.render(alpha);
        timer.updateFPS();
        timer.update();
        window.update();

        if (Settings.SHOW_PERFORMANCE) {
            System.out.println("FPS: " + timer.getFPS() + " UPS: " + timer.getUPS());
        }

        if (window.windowShouldClose()) {
            running = false;
        }
    }

    gameApp.cleanUp();
    window.cleanUp();
}
```

SpriteRenderer:

```
public class SpriteRenderer {

    public StaticShader staticShader;

    public SpriteRenderer(StaticShader staticShader, Matrix4f projectionMatrix) {
        this.staticShader = staticShader;
        staticShader.start();
        staticShader.loadProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
        staticShader.stop();
    }

    public void render(Map<TexturedMesh, List<Entity>> entities, float alpha) {
        for (TexturedMesh mesh : entities.keySet()) {
            prepareTexturedMesh(mesh);
            List<Entity> batch = entities.get(mesh);
            for (Entity entity : batch) {

                Vector2f spritePos = entity.getSprite().getTransform().getPosition();
                Vector2f playerPos = entity.getTransform().getPosition();
                spritePos.x = playerPos.x * alpha + spritePos.x * (1.0f - alpha);
                spritePos.y = playerPos.y * alpha + spritePos.y * (1.0f - alpha);

                prepareInstance(entity.getSprite());
                GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, entity.getSprite().getTexturedMesh().getMesh().getVertexCount());
            }
            unbindTexturedMesh();
        }
    }

    private void unbindTexturedMesh() {
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    private void prepareInstance(Sprite sprite) {
        Transform spriteTransform = sprite.getTransform();
        Matrix4f modelMatrix = Maths.createModelMatrix(spriteTransform.getPosition(), spriteTransform.getScale(), spriteTransform.getRotation());
        staticShader.loadModelMatrix(modelMatrix);
    }

    private void prepareTexturedMesh(TexturedMesh texturedMesh) {
        Mesh mesh = texturedMesh.getMesh();
        mesh.getVao().bind();
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        texturedMesh.getTexture().bind();
    }
}
```

EntityPlayer:

```
public class EntityPlayer extends Entity {

    private float xspeed = 0;
    private float yspeed = 0;

    private final float SPEED = 0.04f;

    public EntityPlayer(Sprite sprite, Vector2f position, Vector2f scale, float rotation) {
        super(sprite, position, scale, rotation);
        this.getSprite().getTransform().setPosition(position);
        this.getSprite().getTransform().setScale(scale);
        this.getSprite().getTransform().setRotation(rotation);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        this.getTransform().setPosition(new Vector2f(this.getTransform().getPosition().x += xspeed, this.getTransform().getPosition().y += yspeed));
    }

    public void input() {
        if (KeyboardHandler.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_RIGHT)) {
            xspeed = SPEED;
        } else if (KeyboardHandler.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_LEFT)) {
            xspeed = -SPEED;
        } else {
            xspeed = 0;
        }

        if (KeyboardHandler.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UP)) {
            yspeed = SPEED;
        } else if (KeyboardHandler.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_DOWN)) {
            yspeed = -SPEED;
        } else {
            yspeed = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Timer:

```
    public class Timer {

    private double lastLoopTime;
    private float timeCount;
    private int fps;
    private int fpsCount;
    private int ups;
    private int upsCount;

    public void init() {
        lastLoopTime = getTime();
    }

    public double getTime() {
        return GLFW.glfwGetTime();
    }

    public float getDelta() {
        double time = getTime();
        float delta = (float) (time - lastLoopTime);
        lastLoopTime = time;
        timeCount += delta;
        return delta;
    }

    public void updateFPS() {
        fpsCount++;
    }

    public void updateUPS() {
        upsCount++;
    }

    // Update the FPS and UPS if a whole second has passed
    public void update() {
        if (timeCount > 1f) {
            fps = fpsCount;
            fpsCount = 0;

            ups = upsCount;
            upsCount = 0;

            timeCount -= 1f;
        }
    }

    public int getFPS() {
        return fps > 0 ? fps : fpsCount;
    }

    public int getUPS() {
        return ups > 0 ? ups : upsCount;
    }

    public double getLastLoopTime() {
        return lastLoopTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this post is really old, but I'm running in this exact problem with the stutter, but using Delphi as a programming language. Same "Fix your timestep" loop. 

I have spent close to 40 hours working on this in the past month. I have the main loop timed to the microsecond, and everything triggers as it should and the animation is really smooth, but it will have some stutter at extremely random moments. I have trimmed down the animation and loop to the bare minimum, a cube moving from left to right, repeating over and over.

VSync or no, frame capping or no. Did you fix your problem?

Comment: @EricFortier without seeing MCVE  just guessing here but do you actually measure time or just use timer interval  as constant? You know at least on windows the timers are not very accurate time source (can be affected by OS any time) For C++ Builder (similar to Delphi) time critical stuff I prefer to measure the elapsed time directly either with `PerformanceCounters` (Windows) or `RDTSC`  (x86 x64). Another source of stuttering might be that your rendering is not synchronized with monitor sync signals along with double/triple buffering or bug in sequence of buffers (swapped them occasionaly)

Comment: @EricFortier for example I got MC perfect emulation and timing Z80 emulator done like this (timing in `[us]`) interconecting other ICs and passing ZEXALL which is way more difficult on timing than just rendering. See this: [Sprites sequence control through DeltaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920247/2521214) and all the sublinks in there it should be a good start point to your problem ... if its not time related then it might be gfx api used what is it (GDI encapsulated in VCL,firemonkey or GL,DX,X11 or what)?

Comment: @EricFortier Also in case you have separate threads for render and physics it might be the core source of your problem syncing them ... locking mechanisms (at least on windows) are a nightmare and usually the behavior changes with each windows version and SP ... making lockless schemes unreliable with updates... My experience lately (from win10+) sometimes even OS locks does not work as expected or at all

Answer (score 0):

Your "fixed time step" is not as smooth as you think.

This code:

```
while (accumulator >= interval) {
    gameApp.update();
    timer.updateUPS();
    accumulator -= interval;
}
```

may run at 10000000Hz or at 0.1Hz depending on how long `gameApp.update()`takes to execute.

**Edit**: You can't take for sure that `timer.getDelta()` is aproximately the same value each time is called. Same goes for `accumulator`, which also depends on the remaining value after last `-=interval` call but starts with a different `delta` each time.

The OS can take more time for its own proccesses, delaying yours. Sometimes your *time-step based on measures* may run fine, and the next second it halts for a few milliseconds, enough to mess those measures.

Also, be aware that sending commands to GPU doesn't guarantee they get processed immediately; perhaps they accumulate and later run all in a row.

If you wish some code to be executed every M milliseconds (e.g. 16.6ms for 60 FPS) then use a **Timer** and **scheduleAtFixedRate()**. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)

The next issue you must deal with is that rendering must be done in a shorter time than the fixed step, or else some delay appears. To achieve this goal send to the GPU most of data (vertices, textures, etc) just once. And for each frame render send only the updated data (the camera position, or just a few objects).

Comment: For the first part I am using my own timer class. (I edited my original post to include it). Im not sure I understand what you are saying. I am currently running the update method at 30 UPS in that while loop. Is this not the same as what the scheduleAtFixedRate() would do? Or is scheduleAtFixedRate() just using ms to measure instead of measuring the amount of times called a second? If thats the case why would it matter which I use wouldn't the result be the same? For you second part I am currently working on implementing that. Is there any resources you can give me on that?

Comment: Also I don't think it has anything to do with the speed of the rendering as I am only dealing with rendering 1 thing which is the player.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why I should use scheduleAtFixedRate(). I would still like to use my own Timer though so I can count fps, ups and calculate a alpha value. Is it correct that what you are saying is to replace my timer with the java timer? And to replace my while loop with scheduleAtFixedRate(). I tried just replacing my while loop with that method and I end up running at about 6270 UPS.