# White flash on the screen

Tags: c++, opengl

In many demoscene productions you can see the effect of flashing white screen when percussion beat happens (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SbGffUzHSs). I have coded such effect and in works fine. Code of fading function (it ie executed in the render() function):

```
void fade() 
{
glLoadIdentity();                                   
glTranslatef (0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_FILL);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE); 

if (alpha <= 1)
{
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);         
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    alpha += 0.0025;
}           
else
{
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha_inv);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);         
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    alpha_inv -= 0.0025;
}

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

return;
}
```

I have two issues:

- I need some kind of parameter for white flash duration control (ie. 1st flash lasts 1 second, 2 flash lasts only 0,25 second)
- The effect has to have the same speed on each computer (slow and fast).

What can I do in the code above to achieve it?

Comment: Yea need an *easing function* that takes t as a parameter.  In order to get t you need a *stopwatch*.

Comment: @Robinson: What do you mean a stopwatch? What is t parameter? How to calculate parameter t? Could you please clarify?

Comment: I gave you some terms to google.

Comment: measuring time is platform dependent On Windows you got performance timers, On PC you got RDTSC but that can be hard to implement properly on mobile HW, you can use system timers but those are usually not accurate, you can have timing thread with `sleep` which is also not very precise nor reliable .... There is also the PIT controller (PC) if OS allows its access ... see [Sprites sequence control through DeltaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920247/2521214)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sprites sequence control through DeltaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917471/sprites-sequence-control-through-deltatime)

Comment: [Good reading for the second bullet point](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)