# Karatsuba multiplication in Python : execution time

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, multiplication

I have recently learned Karatsuba multiplication. In order to fully understand this concept, I have attempted to write the code in Python and compared the running time against classical multiplication. Although the results are equal, the execution time of karatsuba is still the lowest, despite I am using recursive calls. What's wrong with my approach? Some helps would definitely allow me to understand more about algorithm design.

Best

JP

```
print('Karatsuba multiplication in Python')
x=raw_input("first_number=")
y=raw_input("second_number=")
print('------------------------')
x=int(x)
y=int(y)
import math
import time
def karatsuba(x,y):

  x=str(x)
  y=str(y)

  len_x=len(x)
  len_y=len(y)

  if(int(len_x)==1 or int(len_y)==1):    
    return int(x)*int(y)
  else:

    B=10
    exp1=int(math.ceil(len_x/2.0))
    exp2=int(math.ceil(len_y/2.0))
    if(exp1<exp2):
      exp=exp1
    else:
      exp=exp2
    m1=len_x-exp
    m2=len_y-exp
    a=karatsuba(int(x[0:m1]),int(y[0:m2]))
    c=karatsuba(int(x[m1:len_x]),int(y[m2:len_y]))
    b=karatsuba(int(x[0:m1])+int(x[m1:len_x]),int(y[0:m2])+int(y[m2:len_y]))-a-c
    results=a*math.pow(10,2*exp) + b*math.pow(10,exp) + c
    return int(results)

start_time=time.time()
ctrl = x*y
tpt=time.time() - start_time
print x,'*',y,'=',ctrl
print("--- %s seconds ---" % tpt)

start_time=time.time()
output=karatsuba(x,y)
tpt=time.time() - start_time
print 'karatsuba(',x,',',y,')=',output
print("--- %s seconds ---" % tpt)
```

Comment: What are some of the inputs you used and the results? Could you post those?

Comment: what are you comparing it to?

Answer (score 7):

1. **Karatsuba multiplication has bigger overhead then classical binary multiplication**

   the complexity is better but the overhead cause that **karatsuba** is faster for bigger numbers. The better is **Karatsuba** coded the less the treshold operands size.
2. **I see in your code that you convert number to string to get digit count**

   that is **very slow** operation especially for big numbers use logarithms (constant binary to decadic digits ratio) and binary bit count instead. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214) for ideas on how to code **Karatsuba** faster (code is in **C++**)
3. **usage of pow**

   another slow down use table of powers of 10 instead
4. **what are you comparing it to? (originally asked by Padraic Cunningham)**

   **Karatsuba** is faster because it does operations on lower bit-count variables !!! I do not code in **Phyton** at all so I can missing something (like arbitrary int) but I do not see anywhere you lower the data-type with lowering the bit-count **so you will be always slower !!!**. Also nice will be to add example of slow multiplication you are comparing the times to like binary or radix multiplication ... (add what you use). If you use just `*` operator then if you are on some bigint lib then it is possible you are comparing **Karatsuba** with **Karatsuba** or even **Schönhage-Strassen**
5. **time measurement**

   how do you measure time ? The times should be bigger then 10ms if not loop the computations `N` times and measure the whole thing to avoid accuracy problems. Also take in mind scheduling granularity of **OS** look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572772/2521214) if you have no idea what I am writing about

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm should multiply numbers if the are < 10:

```
 if int(len_x) < 10 or int(len_y) < 10:
```

`karatsuba1` is your original code. `karatsuba` is using `if int(len_x) < 10 or int(len_y) < 10`

```
In [17]: %timeit karatsuba1(999,999)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.3 µs per loop

In [18]: %timeit karatsuba(999,999)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 µs per loop
```