# Calling DOS Function in Interrupt service routine in C

Tags: c, dos, interrupt-handling

Is it good practice to call `ftime()` function  in an Interrupt service routine(ISR) in C?

I have written an ISR that reads the buffer from I/O Device when particular interrupt(data ready) is generated.(only one interrupt is handled).

I want to track last time that particular interrupt is received.

Since ISRs have to be as small as possible,is it worth to add one more line to get time using `ftime()`?

Target OS is MS-DOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Since ISRs have to be as small as possible*" -- and probably yours already does to much. Can't you just set some flags and let the main code, outside the ISR, do everything else?

Comment: Dear @FelixPalmen,flag can be set but if we need to implement timeout,i thought we may need time of last data receive event.Please suggest if any better alternative available.

Comment: What time span are you talking about for a timeout?

Comment: Dear @WeatherVane,time span in milli seconds.

Comment: Using `ftime` is overkill, seeing as you don't need time zone or daylight saving information. You might be interested in [this page](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/interrupts/inthandlers1.html) wherein it advises: *Because MS-DOS is not reentrant, a hardware interrupt handler should never call any MS-DOS functions during the actual interrupt process.*

Comment: Note too that the system clock in MS-DOS is not very accurate. Just because `ftime` provides millisecond timing data does not mean it has millisecond accuracy, I believe typically only about 55 millseconds resolution.

Comment: On my relatively modern PC running Windows the resolution of `_ftime` is only about 16 millseconds.

Comment: Probably the easiest is to use a hardware timer dedicated to the interrupt..  Reset it at interval start and read it at interval end.  Alternatively, poll the free-running timer already used by the OS.

Comment: Windows and DOS use differently the internal timers. And under DOS you have only roughly 18 interrupts per seconds ~55ms as @WeatherVane said. Anyway if you are using a modern CPU maybe you can use internal HighSpeed timers.

Comment: @ramus I would go for [rdtsc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572772/2521214) read also the top voted answer there. It has resolution of a single CPU clock cycle. I think it is present from pentium so unless you are on 486 or older it should work. The [PIT](http://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer) timing interrupt is 18.2Hz but can be reprogrammed up to `1.193182 MHz / divider` where divider is 16 bit value