# How to measure execution time of a measurement function? The measurement function also takes time to execute

Tags: c, algorithm, microcontroller

community!

Take an example pseudo-code:

```
start = time(...); /* I do not remember arguments. Long time no std lib usage */
end   = time(...);
actual_measurement_function_call_time = end - start;
```

I want to measure the time it takes for one `time` function to execute.

Take the below diagram:

```
1,2 - is a start of "time" function
*   - some code, not optimized
!   - time value gets copied
1 ************ ! ****** 2 ************ ! ******
```

************ - is measured more or less precisely. but I donno about equipement. it may still differ, how do you think?
****** - I think this part will be the same.

Am I missing something?

The idea is to average, like few function calls to get more stable result. But now, I confused about how to do it.

---

Comment: Yes, the measurement function takes time to execute. That is why you should either measure the times that are considerably longer than the measurement function, or know exactly the overhead of these function and account for these.

Comment: "For a few function calls" - make that a few *million* calls. Possible duplicate is [Execution time of C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program)

Comment: @user14063792468, Consider `clock()` rather than `time()`, usual finer increments.

Comment: The solution is to measure a trivial "no-op" action, so the time is just the measurement overhead.

Comment: If you're using a profiling library, the designers generally have taken all this into account.

Comment: @user14063792468 the `time` function is just for an example. I have no standard library.

Comment: @WeatherVane I can not see results on actual equipment. It is not available to me. I can not make it to be million calls. The code will go to actual equipment. No one will allow me to have a million calls.

Comment: @all updated the tag to `microcontrollers`

Comment: Why not? The question says you are averaging "a few" function calls. Does the function itself take a *lot* of time? By 'function' do you mean a C function, or do you mean an operation of a remote microcontroller, which itself you have no access to?

Comment: @WeatherVane Why not? - I am not sure if the oscillator will be on the same chip. So yes, the operation may be remote. And it is an actual function call, yes. Why it should not be a function call? I do not know a chip, it may change in the future. In addition to all this, I'm totally new to "micro" C areal.

Comment: Your code and your timing diagram look totally fine.  What are you worried about?  If the resolution of `time` is low compared to its running time, you might want to call it 1000 times or something to get a better estimate.  What exactly are you looking for in an answer, if someone decides to write one?

Comment: In uC world use hardware features like timers to measure the time. Then the overhead related to a single register read is not really important

Comment: @DavidGrayson I worried about that the resolution may be low compared to real time. And I can not run measurements much. The code block for measurement will be at the startup/restart. And the requirements are that the  time spent for initialization of a system shall be as little as possible.

Comment: Hi @user14063792468  --  Based on comments from the community, I've deleted my answer.  On the off-chance you found any part of it useful:   Example 1 is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8n8zWo7c8)  .... and ....  example 2 is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vhWjPo6PY).

Comment: You'll have to give more details and ask more specific questions if you want a meaningful answer.  What microcontroller?  What clock speed?  What is the code for `time()`?  Why can't you just characterize it ahead of time on a development board, instead of characterizing it every time the device starts up?  What will you actually be measuring and what accuracy are you hoping for?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I dont own any of equipment. Event more than that, the equipment may change. The code for `time()` is basically a wrapper for AUTOSAR RTE call. So the oscillator theoretically may be on a different device. I cant hope for any accuracy, as the equipment range may be wide.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Sorry, I do not fully understand what you mean by saying that I can characterize it ahead of time.

Comment: what micro controller you use? better ones have hooked binary counter to CPU clock providing pretty accurate time measurement with minimal overhead (like RDTSC on x86). If none present you can use timers in the same way. You can measure empty overhead and substract it from the real measurement but beware pipelineing,prefetch and code/data alignment can mess things up a bit, also using OS and or services might affect measuring so its a good idea to well place EI/DI if possible. See [Negative clock cycle measurements with back-to-back rdtsc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572772/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre We work for a different range of microcontrollers. The decision was made to use OS tick counters. But, we use AUTOSAR as a layer for the OS, and it is a work in progress as of how to use "raw" OS calls in our module.

Comment: @user14063792468 to be absolutely sure You could add some GPIO pin output toggling and measure with Oscilloscope ... beware depending on CPU architecture the execution time might wary between individual runs due to CACHE related stuff (if present),code align (if prefetch present and both calls are not aligned in the same way), OS scheduling (if more tasks are running or OS have its all stuff behind the scenes) and ISR interventions (if interrupts are enabled and used) ... but without having more info about OS and MCU are all just educated guesses of mine

Answer (score 2):

The most simple and straight-forward way is to use an output pin and an oscilloscope. I do this routinely because of the least impact. You can also "abuse" an already used output, for example connected to an LED.

Set the pin to one level at the beginning of the function or before the call of it. Set it to the other level at the end or after the call. If you choose to put the statements into the function, please be aware that commonly C functions have some "invisible" overhead before your first statement and after the last.

To get an impression of the time overhead, you can toggle the pin at some point. As an extra bonus, you can mark different measurements by the number of toggle pulses. Been there, done that, with great insights.

Commonly the time overhead of setting or resetting a pin is by far smaller than the measured time.

Be aware of interrupts that might prolong the pulse, if their ISRs execute during the function to measure. Jitter during periodic measures indicate such effects.

You don't need any extra library, no communication channel to transmit the results, no extra memory. It works even with the smallest microcontrollers, but scales up to any system that gives you output pins.

If you don't want *any* overhead, you need to look into the generated machine code and sum needed clocks. This is also a viable way for not-too-complex microcontrollers.